# Distribute a list of positive numbers into a desired number of sets, aiming to have sums as close as possible between them

Tags: python, optimization, partitioning, linear-programming, pulp

My goal in posting this is to integrate my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78236646/6376297), where I was asked to provide a minimal working example, but also  to ask for advice regarding the code itself, in case someone can suggest a better/faster/more reliable approach. Hence the separate post (not in the same scope as the reproducibility post).

You can imagine several use cases of this concept.
E.g. you can have several files to process, each with different numbers of records, and you want to distribute their processing between N parallel lines, ensuring that each line has more or less the same total number of records to handle.
Or, you could have several objects of different weight, and N people to carry them from A to B, and you want to ensure that each person has more or less the same weight to carry.

See below my code, based on linear programming (essentially an assignment problem coupled with the minimisation of the sum of absolute differences).

For some reason, when run with `threads` > 1, it gives different results on different runs, as per above post.
But it's much slower if I run it with a single thread, so it's a catch-22 situation.

**Any advice for improvement / alternative approaches *that still deliver an absolute optimal solution* (not greedy) would be appreciated.**

```
# Take a list of numbers and partition them into a desired number of sets,
# ensuring that the sum within each set is as close as possible
# to the sum of all numbers divided by the number of sets.

# USER SETTINGS
list_of_numbers = [  21614,   22716, 1344708,    8948,  136944,     819,    7109,
         255182,  556354, 1898763, 1239808,  925193,  173237,   64301,
         147896,  824564,   16028, 1021326,  108042,   72221,  368270,
          17467,    2953,   52942,    1855,  739627,  460833,   30955]
N_sets_to_make = 4

import numpy as np
import pulp
from pulp import *

# Calculate the desired size of each set
S = N_sets_to_make
average_size = sum(list_of_numbers) / S
sizes = [average_size] * S

# Create the coefficient matrix
N = len(list_of_numbers)
A = np.array(list_of_numbers, ndmin = 2)

# Create the pulp model
prob = LpProblem("Partitioning", LpMinimize)

# Create the pulp variables
# x_names : binary variables encoding the presence of each initial number in each final set
x_names = ['x_'+str(i) for i in range(N * S)]
x = [LpVariable(x_names[i], lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat = 'Integer') for i in range(N * S)]
# X_names : continuous positive variables encoding the absolute difference between each final set sum and the desired size
X_names = ['X_'+str(i) for i in range(S)]
X = [LpVariable(X_names[i], lowBound = 0, cat = 'Continuous') for i in range(S)]

# Add the objective to the model (mimimal sum of X_i)
prob += LpAffineExpression([(X[i], 1) for i in range(S) ])

# Add the constraints to the model

# Constraints forcing each initial number to be in one and only one final set
for c in range(N):
    prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],+1) for m in range(S)]) == 1

# Constraints forcing each final set to be non-empty
for m in range(S):
    prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[i],+1) for i in range(m,(m+1)*N)]) >= 1

# Constraints encoding the absolute values
for m in range(S):    
        cs = [c for c in range(N) if A[0,c] != 0]
        prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) - X[m] <= sizes[m]
        prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) + X[m] >= sizes[m]

# Solve the model
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(gapRel = 0, timeLimit = 3600, threads = 1))

# Extract the solution
values_of_x_i = [value(x[i]) for i in range(N * S)]
selected_ind_initial_numbers = [(list(range(N)) * S)[i] for i,l in enumerate(values_of_x_i) if l == 1]
selected_ind_final_sets = [(list((1 + np.repeat(range(S), N)).astype('int64')))[i] for i,l in enumerate(values_of_x_i) if l == 1]
ind_final_set_for_each_initial_number = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(selected_ind_initial_numbers, selected_ind_final_sets))]

# Find the numbers that ended up in each final set
d = dict()
for m, n in sorted(zip(ind_final_set_for_each_initial_number, list_of_numbers)) :
    if m in d :
        d[m].append(n)
    else :
        d[m] = [n]
print(d)

# And their sums
s = [sum(l) for i, l in enumerate(d.values())]
print(s)

# And the absolute differences of their sums from the desired sum
absdiffs = [np.abs(s[i] - sizes[i]) for i in range(len(s))]
print(absdiffs)

# And the absolute fractional differences
print([absdiffs[i]/sizes[i]/S for i in range(len(absdiffs))])
```

---

**EDIT** modification of the code using row-normalised versions of the desired sizes and of the coefficient matrix, often resulting in faster execution (and making the problem independent from the total sum of numbers)

After:

```
sizes = [average_size] * S
```

add:

```
fracs = [1 / S] * S
```

After:

```
A = np.array(list_of_numbers, ndmin = 2)
```

add:

```
An = A / np.sum(A, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
```

Replace:

```
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) - X[m] <= sizes[m]
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) + X[m] >= sizes[m]
```

by:

```
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],An[0,c]) for c in cs]) - X[m] <= fracs[m]
prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],An[0,c]) for c in cs]) + X[m] >= fracs[m]
```

Also, unexpectedly (to me):

```
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(gapRel = 0, timeLimit = 3600, threads = None))
```

Results in a much faster solution (occurring before the time limit is reached) than when the number of threads is specified(?).

---

**EDIT 2** reporting the results of running the code with the changes suggested by AirSquid and the new version of the code shown in the first edit.

Modified version of my code, using `fracs` and `An` instead of `sizes` and `A`, and `threads = None`: very fast run time (~10 s):

```
{1: [8948, 255182, 1021326, 1344708], 2: [2953, 7109, 17467, 64301, 72221, 108042, 136944, 556354, 739627, 925193], 3: [819, 1855, 21614, 173237, 368270, 824564, 1239808], 4: [16028, 22716, 30955, 52942, 147896, 460833, 1898763]}
[2630164, 2630211, 2630167, 2630133]
[4.75, 42.25, 1.75, 35.75]
[4.514919432450865e-07, 4.015902021495769e-06, 1.6633913698503185e-07, 3.3980709412656508e-06]
```

My original code, using `sizes` and `A`, but no `X` variables, as per AirSquid's suggestion, `gapRel = 0.0001`, `threads = None`: almost instant run time:

```
{1: [819, 2953, 64301, 72221, 739627, 824564, 925193], 2: [108042, 255182, 368270, 1898763], 3: [7109, 16028, 22716, 1239808, 1344708], 4: [1855, 8948, 17467, 21614, 30955, 52942, 136944, 147896, 173237, 460833, 556354, 1021326]}
[2629678, 2630257, 2630369, 2630371]
[490.75, 88.25, 200.25, 202.25]
[4.664624655737393e-05, 8.388245050816607e-06, 1.9033949817858644e-05, 1.922405168869868e-05]
```

Combination of the two (`fracs` and `An`, no `X` variables, `gapRel = 0.0001`, `threads = None`): almost instant run time:

```
{1: [819, 17467, 21614, 22716, 64301, 136944, 1021326, 1344708], 2: [1855, 7109, 8948, 30955, 460833, 556354, 739627, 824564], 3: [108042, 255182, 368270, 1898763], 4: [2953, 16028, 52942, 72221, 147896, 173237, 925193, 1239808]}
[2629895, 2630245, 2630257, 2630278]
[273.75, 76.25, 88.25, 109.25]
[2.6020193571229983e-05, 7.247633825776388e-06, 8.388245050816607e-06, 1.0384314694636988e-05]
```

**Conclusion**: if the use of `max_sum` instead of the individual sums of absolute differences always results in close to optimality for all sets (not only the largest one), this method could be very advantageous, especially if combined with the normalisation, if one is prepared to accept a small nonzero relative gap.

---

**Addendum** after further testing

It turns out that the `max_sum`-based approach, even when left to run to completion (i.e. allowed to find an optimal solution, not stopped by the gap or time limit), *does not result in the desired optimality*.

Example:

```
list_of_numbers = [10000] + [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] * 5
N_sets_to_make = 3
```

With original method (min of sum of absolute differences) based on fractions (`fracs`, `An`):

```
# Final sets
{1: [10000],
 2: [200, 300, 300, 400, 500],
 3: [100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  200,
  200,
  200,
  200,
  300,
  300,
  300,
  400,
  400,
  400,
  400,
  500,
  500,
  500,
  500]}

# Their sums
[10000, 1700, 5800]

# Absolute differences
[4166.666666666667, 4133.333333333333, 33.33333333333303]

# Fractional differences
[0.23809523809523814, 0.23619047619047617, 0.0019047619047618874]

# Their sum
0.4761904761904762
```

With `max_sum` method (min of max sum of fractions):

```
# Final sets
{1: [10000],
 2: [500],
 3: [100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  100,
  200,
  200,
  200,
  200,
  200,
  300,
  300,
  300,
  300,
  300,
  400,
  400,
  400,
  400,
  400,
  500,
  500,
  500,
  500]}

# Their sums
[10000, 500, 7000]

# Absolute differences
[4166.666666666667, 5333.333333333333, 1166.666666666667]

# Fractional differences
[0.23809523809523814, 0.30476190476190473, 0.0666666666666667]

# Their sum
0.6095238095238096
```

Comment: Most commercial MIP solvers (opposed to open source solvers) are both much faster and are designed to yield reproducible results even when using multiple threads.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen *"MIP solvers"* ? Any examples, links please?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen : OK thanks we will consider that if this aspect becomes crucial. At the moment I just wanted to explore what was possible with CBC and similar open-source solvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, realize that your toy problem is combinatorially quite vast.

A *very* crude lower bound on the number of options is:

```
c(28, 14) * c(14, 7) * c(7,6) * 1
```

Which exceeds 1e+11.  The true number is likely several additional orders of magnitude.

One strategy to reduce the model size a bit is just to employ a mini-max strategy where you minimize the max size of the largest set, which, depending on how you define "comparing the sums" is probably fine.

This removes `S-1` variables out of your formulation and collapses the constraint matrix substantially.  Your absolute value portion is reduced by 1/2 and each of those constraints only has 1 variable in it, instead of `S` variables.

Do that, and change the RelGap to something **reasonable** and you get nearly instantaneous performance.  With a RelGap of 0.0001, it solves instantly.  If you must solve to 100% optimality guarantee, you're still in for a long haul just because the combinatorial magnitude of the problem and underlying integer structure.

I'd write this slightly differently, but not enough to worry about.  flat indexing and numpy aren't necessary.  I'd just double-index it for clarity and not use Affine Expressions as you are, because the model constructs instantly, and it is easier to read.  (see my other `pulp` posts for examples)

#### Slight mods

```
# USER SETTINGS
list_of_numbers = [  21614,   22716, 1344708,    8948,  136944,     819,    7109,
         255182,  556354, 1898763, 1239808,  925193,  173237,   64301,
         147896,  824564,   16028, 1021326,  108042,   72221,  368270,
          17467,    2953,   52942,    1855,  739627,  460833,   30955]
N_sets_to_make = 4

import numpy as np
import pulp
from pulp import *

# Calculate the desired size of each set
S = N_sets_to_make
average_size = sum(list_of_numbers) / S
sizes = [average_size] * S

# Create the coefficient matrix
N = len(list_of_numbers)
A = np.array(list_of_numbers, ndmin = 2)

# Create the pulp model
prob = LpProblem("Partitioning", LpMinimize)

# Create the pulp variables
# x_names : binary variables encoding the presence of each initial number in each final set
x_names = ['x_'+str(i) for i in range(N * S)]
x = [LpVariable(x_names[i], lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat = 'Integer') for i in range(N * S)]
# X_names : continuous positive variables encoding the absolute difference between each final set sum and the desired size
X_names = ['X_'+str(i) for i in range(S)]
# X = [LpVariable(X_names[i], lowBound = 0, cat = 'Continuous') for i in range(S)]
max_sum = LpVariable(name='max_sum', cat='Continuous')
# Add the objective to the model (mimimal sum of X_i)
prob += LpAffineExpression(max_sum)

# Add the constraints to the model

# Constraints forcing each initial number to be in one and only one final set
for c in range(N):
    prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],+1) for m in range(S)]) == 1

# Constraints forcing each final set to be non-empty
for m in range(S):
    prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[i],+1) for i in range(m,(m+1)*N)]) >= 1

# Constraints encoding the absolute values
for m in range(S):
        cs = [c for c in range(N) if A[0,c] != 0]
        prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) <= max_sum
        # prob += LpAffineExpression([(x[c+m*N],A[0,c]) for c in cs]) + X[m] >= sizes[m]

# Solve the model
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(gapRel = 0.0001, timeLimit = 3600, threads = 1))

# Extract the solution
values_of_x_i = [value(x[i]) for i in range(N * S)]
selected_ind_initial_numbers = [(list(range(N)) * S)[i] for i,l in enumerate(values_of_x_i) if l == 1]
selected_ind_final_sets = [(list((1 + np.repeat(range(S), N)).astype('int64')))[i] for i,l in enumerate(values_of_x_i) if l == 1]
ind_final_set_for_each_initial_number = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(selected_ind_initial_numbers, selected_ind_final_sets))]

# Find the numbers that ended up in each final set
d = dict()
for m, n in sorted(zip(ind_final_set_for_each_initial_number, list_of_numbers)) :
    if m in d :
        d[m].append(n)
    else :
        d[m] = [n]
print(d)

# And their sums
s = [sum(l) for i, l in enumerate(d.values())]
print(s)

# And the absolute differences of their sums from the desired sum
absdiffs = [np.abs(s[i] - sizes[i]) for i in range(len(s))]
print(absdiffs)

# And the absolute fractional differences
print([absdiffs[i]/sizes[i]/S for i in range(len(absdiffs))])
```

Comment: *"mini-max strategy"*? *"Constraint matrix"*? *"RelGap"*? Could you maybe link to some context please so folks know what you are referring to? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not sure what the confusion is.  mini-max is explained in the post and working code is provided that implements it.  RelGap is a setting for the solver the OP *already referenced* and relative gap along with the fundamental concept of a constraint matrix are integral to linear programming and optimization, the 2 tags this is under.  Should I explain that the "equals sign" is actually an "assignment operator" with a link to dox if I post an answer to a Python question?

Comment: @AirSquid : thanks, this is very interesting! Worth a try. The relative gap idea is indeed what we would use to limit the run time; or we use a smaller max run time, because very often the solver gets really close to a very good solution, even better than the relative gap we can think of, but carries on because it thinks (or knows) it may get a better one. As for the code, yes, I wanted to use double indexing, but in my original code I was using R (Rsymphony), which uses matrices, so I had to rewrite it all in an unfamiliar format (the pulp one), and it's a miracle I even managed to do this.

Comment: As for the combinatorial size, yes I am well aware of that, that's why I am amazed the solver can even solve such problems at all. I suppose it has very clever heuristics or other strategies, despite not being commercial. And this is nothing BTW. In other types of related problems that we tackle with code quite similar to this one, matrix A can have thousands of columns and hundreds of rows. And CBC still solves them. So I am really nitpicking here. BTW for completeness I will post a modification of my own code, which usually also helps.

Comment: @AirSquid : I applied your suggestion. The results are interesting, so thanks again for your input. I am however tempted to delete the question, because as usual I am getting downvoted for absolutely no logical reason whatsoever. It is incredibly annoying to do all this work, try to contribute to a useful discussion and exploration of interesting methods, only to get punished for it by the usual tiresome anonymous imbeciles who, being unable to do anything worthwhile themselves, find it gratifying to humiliate others.

Comment: Actually, i see people are already voting to close the question, so I will just go ahead and delete it. Sorry, but this is unacceptable. Invariably, almost every single time I post something, I get immediately downvoted or my questions get closed down, despite the fact that users reply or comment positively and constructively. There should be more control on people's actions, and whoever downvotes should provide reasons and explanations, otherwise this is pointless. I am actually actively discouraged from using this platform by this incredibly stupid way of working.

Comment: Well actually no, I cannot delete it. "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.". So I have to have my SO reputation reduced for no reason whatsoever, nothing to do about it. I guess the best option is to leave then. I already left several others stack exchange sites, where my most innocent and well-meaning questions were met with absolutely horrific downvoting/closing coordinated attacks. Probably nothing personal, but then this platform is really heading to its end IMO.

Comment: You don't need to delete it.  the q is probably getting some negativity because you are linking/extending other question (usually discouraged), and editing the question to change scope, and the comments are getting a little sassy--I am partially to blame.  :/   The more focused the question, the better, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: If this is a "real project" and not just a learning exercise, you may need to seek some help outside of SO, as the best approaches may likely change with the true scale, precision, and timeliness requirements.  I have a link in my profile if you wish to continue a discussion outside of SO.

Comment: @AirSquid : thanks. I accepted your answer so maybe we can put an end to this. The list of numbers example is not a project, but we do use this code to do other machine-learning-related stuff. For the rest, I agree with all you said. It doesn't change the fact that my question was not vague (unlike the people voting to close it are saying); there is one single question. Further proof: you read it and gave a very useful and articulate answer. And I took up your advice and posted further work and code. What more do these moderators want? Enough of this nonsense already! Every single time...

Comment: And yes, the language inevitably gets 'sassy', when people put a lot of effort into making honest, useful contributions to general knowledge and collaborative exchange, only to be rewarded with moronic 'judgment' and 'negativity' by equally moronic people, who clearly have nothing better to do with their time. Perhaps one day we will see some non-negative contribution from them? Or have they actually decided to dedicate their whole life to turning this once great platform into a toxic, unpleasant, judgmental troll playground? In that case they're fully succeeding, congrats to them(!).

Comment: IMHO the code `for m in range(S):
        cs = [c for c in range(N) if A[0,c] != 0]` is invariant to `m` and thus can be moved outside of the loop.

Comment: @user1016274 : you're right. To make these examples I adapted some more complicated code with more nested loops (when A has more than 1 row for instance, so instead of 0 you have the other loop index), and forgot these details. I suppose however that's not slowing down the code too much; the main improvement I could see so far was the one resulting from AirSquid's suggestion. I still don't exactly know how/why it works and if it's applicable in general, but surely it does remove a lot of variables and constaints, and this should usually help reduce the run time.